# No output from echo

Tags: bash, echo

The below script has passed verification @ [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

```
#!/bin/bash
SRCDIR='/home/vinod/src'
ALLSRCFILES=${SRCDIR}/.
PODMANCMD='podman ps'
GITWORKSPACE='/workspace/vinod'
CONTAINER=$(eval "${PODMANCMD}" | awk 'NR==2{print$1}')
DSTDIR="${CONTAINER}:${GITWORKSPACE}/dst"
CPCMD=${PODMANCMD} ${ALLSRCFILES} "$DSTDIR"
echo "$DSTDIR"
echo "$CPCMD"
```

I get the output for the penultimate echo, but not the last one, when testing this on Linux.

Any thoughts?

TIA

Comment: QUOTE the WHOLE assignment of `CPCMD`., but I have a feeling this one is a [classic](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Don't store commands in variables if you can avoid it; there are many ways for it to go wrong. In general, use variables to store data, functions to store executable code. The `eval` command is also a massive bug magnet.

Comment: I see `podman ps` but also `CPCMD`. Maybe you mean `podman cp`?

Comment: You should have got an error message from `CPCMD=${PODMANCMD} ${ALLSRCFILES} "$DSTDIR"` (something like _command not found_). If not, please turn on tracing (`set -x`), run the script and post a screenshot from the execution. Another possible problem would be a missing newline at the end of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax:

```
CPCMD=${PODMANCMD} ${ALLSRCFILES} "$DSTDIR"
```

Means: "Run the command resulting from the expansion of `${ALLSRCFILES} "$DSTDIR"` in an environment in which the environment variable `CPCMD` has the value of the expansion of `${PODMANCMD}`.

This environment is only set up in the child process of the command; it doesn't affect the current shell.

You want quotes around the whole thing if you want an assignment. If there are additional argument words to the right of an assignment, it looks like the environment variable override syntax for a command.

Comment: @kvantour The syntax is a command. (Likely invalid.) `var1=value1 var2=value2 ... word1 word2 word3 ...` is a command syntax. For instance, try this `FOO=bar blurb blech`.   Then `echo $FOO`. You will see that `FOO` contains nothing. The command is `blurb blech`, with environment variable `FOO=bar`.   Whether the `blurb` command exists or not, no assignment takes place to the variable `FOO`.

Comment: Kaz, you are totally correct! My apologies.